# Mi app crashea al precionar el boton de mostrar, eliminar

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, sqlite

Este es mi código de creación de la base de datos.

```
override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase) {
    db.execSQL("create table if not exists automotora (chasis int primary key, marca text, cilindrada text, detalle text, precio text, carroceria text)")
}

override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
}
```

}

El error me arroja en la variable fila donde según la consola no encuentra la columna chasis

```
    boton2.setOnClickListener {
        val admin = AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this, "administracion", null, 2)
        val bd = admin.writableDatabase
        val fila = bd.rawQuery("select marca, cilindrada, detalle, precio, carroceria from automotora where chasis = ${et1.text}", null)
        if (fila.moveToFirst()){
            et2.setText(fila.getString(0))
            et3.setText((fila.getString(1)))
            et4.setText((fila.getString(2)))
            et5.setText((fila.getString(3)))
            et6.setText((fila.getString(4)))

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No existe un articulo con dicho chasis", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        bd.close()
    }
```

Lo mismo pasa con el borrar datos, la consola arroja que no se encuentra la columna chasis

```
    boton3.setOnClickListener {
        val admin = AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this, "administracion", null, 2)
        val bd = admin.writableDatabase
        val cant = bd.delete("automotora", "chasis ${et1.text}", null)
        bd.close()
        et1.setText("")
        et2.setText("")
        et3.setText("")
        et4.setText("")
        et5.setText("")
        et6.setText("")
        if (cant==1){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Se borro el articulo de dicho codigo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No existe un articulo con dicho codigo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
```

Este es el error en la consola

E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such column: ss in "select marca, cilindrada, detalle, precio, carroceria from automotora where chasis = ss"
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.prueba3, PID: 23763
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: ss (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: select marca, cilindrada, detalle, precio, carroceria from automotora where chasis = ss
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1045)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:652)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:590)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:61)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:46)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1545)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1484)
at com.example.prueba3.MainActivity.onCreate$lambda-1(MainActivity.kt:49)
at com.example.prueba3.MainActivity.$r8$lambda$OAsTORK3ddlBuUO-BH_u3j9ljJE(Unknown Source:0)
at com.example.prueba3.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.onClick(Unknown Source:15)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1219)
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 23763 SIG: 9

Comment: Por qué no lees el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender cómo preguntar (y de paso ganas una medalla)? Edita la pregunta, borra las capturas y copia el código correctamente formateado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error se define aquí:

> SQLiteException: no such column: ss (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while
> compiling: select marca, cilindrada, detalle, precio, carroceria from
> automotora where chasis = ss at
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native
> Method

Estás realizando una consulta donde buscas cuando el campo "chasis" tiene el valor "ss", esto no está funcionando, ya que debes contener entre comillas el valor que deseas consultar:

```
"select marca, cilindrada, detalle, precio, carroceria from automotora where chasis = ss"
```

la consulta debería realizarse de esta forma, conteniendo el valor de `et1.text` entre comillas:

```
 val fila = bd.rawQuery("select marca, cilindrada, detalle, precio, carroceria from automotora where chasis = '${et1.text}'", null)
```

la consulta se realizaría de esta forma:

```
"select marca, cilindrada, detalle, precio, carroceria from automotora where chasis = 'ss'"
```